# Ruby convert Object to Hash

Tags: ruby, object, hashmap, instance-variables

Let's say I have a `Gift` object with `@name = "book"` & `@price = 15.95`. What's the best way to convert that to the Hash `{name: "book", price: 15.95}` in Ruby, not Rails (although feel free to give the Rails answer too)?

Comment: Would @gift.attributes.to_options do?

Comment: 1) Is gift a ActiveRecord object? 2)can we assume @name/@price are not just instance variables but also reader accessors? 3) you want only name and price or all the attributes in a gift whatever they are?

Comment: @tokland, 1) no, `Gift` is [exactly like @nash has defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030553/ruby-convert-object-to-hash/5030763#5030763), except, 2) sure, the instance variables can have reader accessors. 3) All the attributes in gift.

Comment: Ok. The question about instance variables/readers access was to know if wanted an outside access (nash) or inside method (levinalex). I updated my answer for the "inside" approach.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
class Gift
  def initialize
    @name = "book"
    @price = 15.95
  end
end

gift = Gift.new
hash = {}
gift.instance_variables.each {|var| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = gift.instance_variable_get(var) }
p hash # => {"name"=>"book", "price"=>15.95}
```

Alternatively with `each_with_object`:

```
gift = Gift.new
hash = gift.instance_variables.each_with_object({}) { |var, hash| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = gift.instance_variable_get(var) }
p hash # => {"name"=>"book", "price"=>15.95}
```

Comment: You can use inject to skip initializing the variable: gift.instance_variables.inject({}) { |hash,var| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = gift.instance_variable_get(var); hash }

Comment: Nice. I replaced `var.to_s.delete("@")` with `var[1..-1].to_sym` to get symbols.

Comment: Don't use inject, use `gift.instance_variables.each_with_object({}) { |var,hash| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = gift.instance_variable_get(var) }` and get rid of the trailing `; hash`

Comment: I will never understand the ruby fetish for `each`. `map` and `inject` are much more powerful. This is one design qualm I have with Ruby:  `map` and `inject` are implemented with `each`. It's simply bad computer science.

Comment: Slightly more concise: `hash = Hash[gift.instance_variables.map { |var| [var.to_s[1..-1], gift.instance_variable_get(var)] } ]`

Answer (score 327):

Just say (current object) `.attributes`

`.attributes` returns a `hash` of any `object`. And it's much cleaner too.

Comment: Note that this is an ActiveModel-specific method, not a Ruby method.

Comment: In the case of Sequel -- use `.values`: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/InstanceMethods.html

Comment: `instance_values` can be used for all ruby objects for the similar output.

Comment: Not a ruby expert, but isn't this a much cleaner method than all others? It looks like the best answer to me, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 53):

Implement `#to_hash`?

```
class Gift
  def to_hash
    hash = {}
    instance_variables.each { |var| hash[var.to_s.delete('@')] = instance_variable_get(var) }
    hash
  end
end


h = Gift.new("Book", 19).to_hash
```

Comment: Technically, it should be .to_hash, since # indicates class methods.

Comment: Actually, no. RDoc documentation says: `Use :: for describing class methods, # for describing instance methods, and use . for example code` (source: http://ruby-doc.org/documentation-guidelines.html) Also, official documentation (like the ruby CHANGELOG, https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_0/NEWS) uses `#` for instance methods and the dot for class methods pretty consistently.

Comment: Please use inject instead of this antipattern.

Comment: One-liner variant using `each_with_object`: `instance_variables.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |element, hash| hash["#{element}".delete("@").to_sym] = instance_variable_get(element) }`

Answer (score 53):

```
Gift.new.instance_values # => {"name"=>"book", "price"=>15.95}
```

Comment: This is Rails, Ruby itself doesn't have `instance_values`. Note that Matt asked for a Ruby way, specifically not Rails.

Comment: He also said feel free to give the Rails answer as well... so I did.

Comment: God to see both versions here ;) Liked it

Comment: I'd preface your answer with something like "Rails provides the #instance_values method"

Answer (score 23):

You can use `as_json` method. It'll convert your object into hash.

But, that hash will come as a value to the name of that object as a key. In your case,

```
{'gift' => {'name' => 'book', 'price' => 15.95 }}
```

If you need a hash that's stored in the object use `as_json(root: false)`. I think by default root will be false. For more info refer official ruby guide

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Answer (score 14):

For Active Record Objects

```
module  ActiveRecordExtension
  def to_hash
    hash = {}; self.attributes.each { |k,v| hash[k] = v }
    return hash
  end
end

class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecordExtension
  ....
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecordExtension
  ....
end
```

and then just call

```
gift.to_hash()
purch.to_hash()
```

Comment: funny it's not part of the Rails framework. Seems like a useful thing to have there.

Comment: The attributes method returns a new hash with the values in - so no need to create another in the to_hash method.  Like so: attribute_names.each_with_object({}) { |name, attrs|
        attrs[name] = read_attribute(name)
      } . See here:  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb

Comment: you could have done this with map, your side-effect implementation is hurting my mind man!

Answer (score 12):

```
class Gift
  def to_hash
    instance_variables.map do |var|
      [var[1..-1].to_sym, instance_variable_get(var)]
    end.to_h
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are not in an Rails environment (ie. don't have ActiveRecord available), this may be helpful:

```
JSON.parse( object.to_json )
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write a very elegant solution using a functional style.

```
class Object
  def hashify
    Hash[instance_variables.map { |v| [v.to_s[1..-1].to_sym, instance_variable_get v] }]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Recursively convert your objects to hash using 'hashable' gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/hashable)
**Example**

```
class A
  include Hashable
  attr_accessor :blist
  def initialize
    @blist = [ B.new(1), { 'b' => B.new(2) } ]
  end
end

class B
  include Hashable
  attr_accessor :id
  def initialize(id); @id = id; end
end

a = A.new
a.to_dh # or a.to_deep_hash
# {:blist=>[{:id=>1}, {"b"=>{:id=>2}}]}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks you!

Answer (score 4):

You should override the `inspect` method of your object to return the desired hash, or just implement a similar method without overriding the default object behaviour.

If you want to get fancier, you can iterate over an object's instance variables with [object.instance_variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.src/M001027.html)

Answer (score 4):

Might want to try `instance_values`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To plagiarize @Mr. L in a comment above, try `@gift.attributes.to_options`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `symbolize_keys` and in-case you have nested attributes we can use `deep_symbolize_keys`:

```
gift.as_json.symbolize_keys => {name: "book", price: 15.95}
```

Answer (score 1):

Produces a shallow copy as a hash object of just the model attributes

```
my_hash_gift = gift.attributes.dup
```

Check the type of the resulting object

```
my_hash_gift.class
=> Hash
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need nested objects to be converted as well.

```
# @fn       to_hash obj {{{
# @brief    Convert object to hash
#
# @return   [Hash] Hash representing converted object
#
def to_hash obj
  Hash[obj.instance_variables.map { |key|
    variable = obj.instance_variable_get key
    [key.to_s[1..-1].to_sym,
      if variable.respond_to? <:some_method> then
        hashify variable
      else
        variable
      end
    ]
  }]
end # }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gift.new.attributes.symbolize_keys

Answer (score 0):

To do this without Rails, a clean way is to store attributes on a constant.

```
class Gift
  ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :price]
  attr_accessor(*ATTRIBUTES)
end
```

And then, to convert an instance of `Gift` to a `Hash`, you can:

```
class Gift
  ...
  def to_h
    ATTRIBUTES.each_with_object({}) do |attribute_name, memo|
      memo[attribute_name] = send(attribute_name)
    end
  end
end
```

This is a good way to do this because it will only include what you define on `attr_accessor`, and not every instance variable.

```
class Gift
  ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :price]
  attr_accessor(*ATTRIBUTES)

  def create_random_instance_variable
    @xyz = 123
  end

  def to_h
    ATTRIBUTES.each_with_object({}) do |attribute_name, memo|
      memo[attribute_name] = send(attribute_name)
    end
  end
end

g = Gift.new
g.name = "Foo"
g.price = 5.25
g.to_h
#=> {:name=>"Foo", :price=>5.25}

g.create_random_instance_variable
g.to_h
#=> {:name=>"Foo", :price=>5.25}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started using structs to make easy to hash conversions.
Instead of using a bare struct I create my own class deriving from a hash this allows you to create your own functions and it documents the properties of a class.

```
require 'ostruct'

BaseGift = Struct.new(:name, :price)
class Gift < BaseGift
  def initialize(name, price)
    super(name, price)
  end
  # ... more user defined methods here.
end

g = Gift.new('pearls', 20)
g.to_h # returns: {:name=>"pearls", :price=>20}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Nate's answer which I haven't been able to compile:

**Option 1**

```
class Object
    def to_hash
        instance_variables.map{ |v| Hash[v.to_s.delete("@").to_sym, instance_variable_get(v)] }.inject(:merge)
   end
end
```

And then you call it like that:

```
my_object.to_hash[:my_variable_name]
```

**Option 2**

```
class Object
    def to_hash
        instance_variables.map{ |v| Hash[v.to_s.delete("@"), instance_variable_get(v)] }.inject(:merge)
   end
end
```

And then you call it like that:

```
my_object.to_hash["my_variable_name"]
```